# store error message in session and display on another page

Tags: php, html, session

there is a scenario that i have in my hand at present.I have 2 pages `index.php and code.php.`

the user first goes to index.php page and then is redirected to code.php page and back to index.php page.

in case some error occurs in code.php page, i need to display that error on index.php page when it gets redirected back to index page.

i stored the error message in session like this and then redirected the page bsck to index.php page

```
$_SESSION["errormsg"]='please try again';
header("Location: index.php");
```

but if i echo this session message in index.php page it gets displayed evertime when the page gets loaded, however i want only once when the index page comes after the code.php page. can anyone tell how it can be done

Comment: try `session_start();` at the top before using or assigning session variable.

Comment: every time when page load use below condition
if(isset($_SESSION["errormsg"]) && $_SESSION["errormsg"] !== 0){
   echo $_SESSION["errormsg"];
   unset($_SESSION["errormsg"]);
}

Comment: try to simple just add exit(); after header("Location: index.php"); and then try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that, the best way to show error message via session is having separate message file like message.php.

Step 1 :
you just have to set the session with your error message in your code.php.

$_SESSION["errormsg"]='please try again';

Step 2 :

- Now create new file with the name "message.php".
- Store the session error message into new variable.

$error = $_SESSION["errormsg"];

Step 3 :

then, unset the session or destroy the session.

```
 // remove all session variables
 session_unset(); 

 // destroy the session 
 session_destroy();
```

Step 4 :

- Now echo that error variable in formatted div tag so that your error looks good and also eye catchy.

```html
<div id='alert'><div class=' alert alert-block alert-info fade in center'>$error</div></div>
```

Step 5 :

- Now, in you index.php file, have a method to check that if the session variable "errormsg" is set or not.
- If the session variable is set then call the message.php file right away. it will echo that div in you index.php file .

I think this would give you full answer.

Comment: replace session_unset(); with unset($_SESSION["errormsg"]); do not go the lazy way where u might unset the user's session

Comment: it'd be easier if you just pasted the code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple condition to check if the particular session is set or not.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["errormsg"])) {
    $error = $_SESSION["errormsg"];
    session_unset($_SESSION["errormsg"]);
} else {
    $error = "";
}

echo $error;
```

Comment: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: session_unset() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given.... is the error i get on the third line

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered 3 years ago, but i thought i could add something into the same topic. I hope it is helpful.

If session message in index.php page gets displayed every time you  open the page, it means that session variable "errormsg" has not been cleared.

Therefore use `unset($_SESSSION['errormsg']);` to remove it after display as suggested above.

However when you do this, another problem occurs the error message wont be displayed with this code in code.php:

```
$_SESSION["errormsg"]='please try again';

header("Location: index.php");
```

Because when you redirect to the index page, session variable is cleared before message gets displayed.

To solve this:

Avoid redirecting the page more than once.

in code.php use:

```
$_SESSION["errormsg"]='please try again';
```

without redirecting to the index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session_start()` at starting of page as you are assigning session variable value without actually starting the session.

Also you can use the condition

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['variablename']))
{
 //your code
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Ensure that a session exists (just in case)
if( !session_id() )
{
    session_start();
}
```

Function

```
/**
 * Function to create and display error and success messages
 * @access public
 * @param string session name
 * @param string message
 * @param string display class
 * @return string message
 */
function flash( $name = '', $message = '', $class = 'success fadeout-message' )
{
    //We can only do something if the name isn't empty
    if( !empty( $name ) )
    {
        //No message, create it
        if( !empty( $message ) &amp;& empty( $_SESSION[$name] ) )
        {
            if( !empty( $_SESSION[$name] ) )
            {
                unset( $_SESSION[$name] );
            }
            if( !empty( $_SESSION[$name.'_class'] ) )
            {
                unset( $_SESSION[$name.'_class'] );
            }

            $_SESSION[$name] = $message;
            $_SESSION[$name.'_class'] = $class;
        }
        //Message exists, display it
        elseif( !empty( $_SESSION[$name] ) &amp;& empty( $message ) )
        {
            $class = !empty( $_SESSION[$name.'_class'] ) ? $_SESSION[$name.'_class'] : 'success';
            echo '<div class="'.$class.'" id="msg-flash">'.$_SESSION[$name].'</div>';
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
            unset($_SESSION[$name.'_class']);
        }
    }
}


//Set the first flash message with default class
flash( 'example_message', 'This content will show up on example2.php' );

//Set the second flash with an error class
flash( 'example_class', 'This content will show up on example2.php with the error class', 'error' );
```

Displaying
the
messages

```
<?php flash( 'example_message' ); ?>
<?php flash( 'example_class' ); ?>
```